# binding enum values on to repositoryItemButtonEdit1 dev express control

Tags: c#, devexpress

Could you please help me on to how we can  bind enum values on to repositoryItemButtonEdit1 dev express control?

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear to me why you are talking about binding Enum values via the [RepositoryItemButtonEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsButtonEdittopic) exactly, because this editor is not intended to work with Enum values.

So, to bind Enum values, I suggest you use the [RepositoryItemImageComboBox](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsImageComboBoxEdittopic) editor. This editor is specially designed to work with Enums - just try to use it's [AddEnum(Type)](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsImageComboBoxItemCollection_AddEnumtopic(7lgsNg)) method as follows:

```
imageComboBoxEdit1.Properties.Items.AddEnum(typeof(YourEnumType));
```